# How can I select some columns of table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Here is my code:

```
$arr = Users::all()->toArray();
```

It returns an array of all table's columns. But I don't need to all columns. I need to return only these columns: `'id', 'name', 'email', 'age'`. I've searched about that and I figured this out: *(using `pluck()` function)*

```
$arr = Users::pluck('id', 'name', 'email', 'age')->toArray();
```

But it doesn't return expected result. It returns this:

```
array:7 [▼
  "John" => 1
  "Peter" => 2
  "Jack" => 3
  "Ali" => 4
  "Teresco" => 5
  "Mark" => 6
  "Barman" => 7
]
```

As you see, there isn't `email` and `age` columns. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try like this: `$arr = Users::get(array('columns'....));`

Comment: @S.I. Yeah it works .. I tested it .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect arrays of columns in `get()` like this:

```
$arr = Users::get(array('id', 'name', 'email', 'age'))->toArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects) method like this,

```
Users::select('id', 'name', 'email', 'age')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Users::with(array('user'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','username');
    }))->get();
```

It will only select id and username from other table. I hope this will help others.

Comment: Where is `toArray()` ?

Comment: @S.I. Hah .. You have great skills at sarching `:-P`